# jQuery Multiple AutoCompletes

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I'm using jQuery UI Autocomplete, on my page i've got three inputs to put autocomplete on i'm trying to handle this as so:

```
    var elem = $('.tags');

    var groups = ["C","C++","Java","JavaScript","PHP","Python","Ruby"];
    var users = ["John Doe","Jane Doe","Jim Doe"];
    var ips = ["test1","test2","test3"];

    elem.autocomplete({
        source:  elem.attr('data-remote-source').split(','),
    });
```

But this is not working for me, am i doing something wrong in my code?

The HTML code is as follows:

```
<input type="search" name="" data-remote-source="groups" class="tags" placeholder="Search for groups" />

<input type="search" name="" data-remote-source="users" class="tags" placeholder="Search for users" />

<input type="search" name="" data-remote-source="ips" class="tags" placeholder="Search for ips" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`elem.attr('data-remote-source')` is returning a string 'groups'

The reason its always returning the same string is `elem` is global (outside the autocomplete initializer) and matches all 3 inputs. jQuery is returning the first match.

Then you are trying to split that string at commas, returning `[ "groups" ]`

Here is a demo of that - all 3 autocompletes will match 'groups' and nothing else: http://jsfiddle.net/86y2W/

Here's the fix:

```
var elem = $('.tags');

var data = {
    "groups": ["C","C++","Java","JavaScript","PHP","Python","Ruby"],
    "users": ["John Doe","Jane Doe","Jim Doe"],
    "ips": ["test1","test2","test3"]
};

elem.each(function(i,e){
    $(e).autocomplete({
        source:  data[$(e).attr('data-remote-source')]
    });
});
```

This uses the string (for example `groups`) to lookup the actual array from the `data` variable

Heres the same fiddle, updated with this code: http://jsfiddle.net/86y2W/1/